# Solving for $\sin(n \cdot\arcsin(x))$ when n takes on any integer value.

Tags: trigonometry

> > Solving for $\sin(n \cdot\arcsin(x))$ when n takes on any integer value.
> >
> > How would I go about tackling this question for large numbers of n? I was able to compute it by hand for values of $n$ up to $4$ but there has to be an easier way to solve it for numbers like $50$ etc...

Comment: Are oyu familiar with Chebyshev polynomials and their relationship with [multiple-angle formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html)?  So, if you can solve for $\cos(\sin^{-1} x)$ and $\sin(\sin^{-1} x)$, you can form a polynomial of those giving your multiple angle solution.

Comment: Try using the imaginary part of the complex number definition as a power of e.

Comment: Can you show the first four you said you found? I think it would be helpful for eventual answerers.

Comment: Check this link out, hope this helps
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407337/adriaan-van-roomens-45th-degree-equation-in-1593

Answer (score 3):

If $U_n$ denotes de $n-$th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, we have :

$$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R},\quad\sin((n+1)\theta)=\sin(\theta)\,U_{n}(\cos(\theta))$$

So, for all $x\in[-1,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}^\star$ :

$$\sin(n\arcsin(x))=x\,U_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$

It remains to explain how to compute effectively $U_n(t)$ for every pair $(n,t)$.

A simple way is to use the recurrence relation :

$$U_0(t)=1\qquad U_1(t)=2t\qquad \forall n\ge2,\,U_n(t)=2t\,U_{n-1}(t)-U_{n-2}(t)$$

Comment: Hello sir. I'm having a problem where I need to use the equation you typed above ChebyshevT(x)=x*ChebyshevU(n-1,sqrt(1-x^2)) but x needs to be outside of [-1,1].  My hypothesis is that the equation holds true even when x is a complex number. Do you have any proof that im wrong?

Comment: @RobertPuscasu The correct relation is $\sin(nx)=\sin(x)\,ChebyshevU(n-1,cos(x))$. Here $\cos(x)\in[-1,1]$ and you would like to replace it by something lying outside this interval. You could maybe use the following relation, which is also true : $\sinh(nx)=\sinh(x)\,Chebyshev(n-1,\cosh(x))$

Comment: Thank you sir...